# mysqlclient error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, mysql, pip

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I was trying to connect Django to a MySQL server, but I encountered some issues. I was unable to install mysqlclient. I tried various methods shown in videos, but none of them worked for me. Is there anything else I should try? Thanks in advance. I'm using Windows 10, and I've seen some solutions that work for Linux and macOS, but they don't seem to work on Windows.

Comment: "encountered some issues" tells us nothing at all.  What happened, exactly?  And why did you choose `mysqlclient`?  That's not the recommended MySQL adapter.